# Snowflake and Regular Expressions - issue when implementing known good expression in SF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for some assistance in debugging a [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html) statement.

I have been using an online regular expressions editor to build expressions, and then the SF regexp_* functions to implement them. I've attempted to remain consistent with the SF regex implementation, but I'm seeing an inconsistency in the returned results that I'm hoping someone can explain :)

My intent is to replace commas within the text (excluding commas with double-quoted text) with a new delimiter (#^#).

Sample text string:

```
"Foreign Corporate Name Registration","99999","Valuation Research",,"Active Name",02/09/2020,"02/09/2020","NEVADA","UNITED STATES",,,"123 SOME STREET",,"MILWAUKEE","WI","53202","UNITED STATES","123 SOME STREET",,"MILWAUKEE","WI","53202","UNITED STATES",,,,,,,,,,,,
```

RegEx command and Substitution (working in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)):

```
([("].*?["])*?(,)
```

```
\1#^#
```

regex101.com Result:

```
"Foreign Corporate Name Registration"#^#"99999"#^#"Valuation Research"#^##^#"Active Name"#^#02/09/2020#^#"02/09/2020"#^#"NEVADA"#^#"UNITED STATES"#^##^##^#"123 SOME STREET"#^##^#"MILWAUKEE"#^#"WI"#^#"53202"#^#"UNITED STATES"#^#"123 SOME STREET"#^##^#"MILWAUKEE"#^#"WI"#^#"53202"#^#"UNITED STATES"#^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^#
```

When I try and implement this same logic in SF using REGEXP_REPLACE(), I am using the following statement:

```
SELECT TOP 500
    A.C1
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE((A."C1"),'([("].*?["])*?(,)','\\1#^#') AS BASE
FROM
    "<Warehouse>"."<database>"."<table>" AS A
```

This statement returns the result for BASE:

```
"Foreign Corporate Name Registration","99999","Valuation Research",,"Active Name",02/09/2020,"02/09/2020","NEVADA","UNITED STATES",,,"123 SOME STREET",,"MILWAUKEE","WI","53202","UNITED STATES","123 SOME STREET",,"MILWAUKEE","WI","53202","UNITED STATES"#^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^##^#
```

As you can see when comparing the results, the SF result set is only replacing commas at the tail-end of the text.

Can anyone tell me why the results between regex101.com and SF are returning different results with the same statement? Is my expression non-compliant with the SF implementation of RegEx - and if yes, can you tell me why?

Many many thanks for your time and effort reading this far!

Happy Wednesday,
Casey.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `.*?` to achieve **lazy matching** for regexing is limited to PCRE, which Snowflake does not support. To see this, in `regex101.com`, change your 'flavor" to be anything other than `PCRE (PHP)`; you will see that your `([("].*?["])*?(,)` regex no longer achieves what you are expecting.

I believe that this will work for your purposes:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(A.C1,'("[^"]*")*,','\\1#^#')
```